# Redirected to Classic From Lightning

Tags: visualforce, standard

We have placed VF page in the account detail page, we are using lightning.
In VF page we placed a button, if user clicks on button then it takes us to salesforce   standard edit page.
Issue here is, for one user when click on button , standard edit page is opening in  classic mode instead of lightning.
Please help me to solve.

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question to include the related code?

Comment: Also, Does that user have access to both Classic and Lightning? Could you please check whether he opens both at the same time in a different tab or something like that? Is it happening every time for him?

Comment: @sanketkumar yes user has access for both classic and lightning and
user getting this issue only for few records.